# Compare elements by attribute and show the correct one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list with divs and a dropdown menu. The list with divs and the dropdown menu divs have the same data attribute (data-num). When a div in the dropdown menu is clicked I want to show the div with the same data attribute and hide the others. I tried something like this but it's only giving me the first div from the list:

```
$('#chooseAnnexDropdown ul li').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var sibs = $(this).siblings();
    var thisAttr = $(this).attr('data-num');
    var thisParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

    var theProducts = thisParent.find('.theProduct');
    var theProductsAttr = $(theProducts).attr('data-num');
    console.log(theProductsAttr);

    that.click(function(){
        if ( thisAttr === theProductsAttr ) {
            // show the product div with the correct attribute and hide the others
        }
    });
});
```

So how do i loop through each element in my dropdown and then compare it to my other list and show the correct div?

Here is some of the HTML code:

```
<div id="configurator">
<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div id="chooseAnnexDropdown" class="confDropdown">
    <ul>
        <li class="block_2" data-num="block_2">Atelier</li>
        <li class="block_3" data-num="block_3">Bryggerhus</li>
        <li class="block_4" data-num="block_4">Smørebod</li>
        <li class="block_5" data-num="block_5">Bakstehus</li>
        <li class="block_6" data-num="block_6">Sportsrom</li>
        <li class="block_7" data-num="block_7">Boenhet</li>
        <li class="block_8" data-num="block_8">Ingen</li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<!-- end dropdown menu -->

{% for i in 1..39 %}
    {% for block in entry['hyttekonf'  ~i] %}
        <div class="theProduct" data-num="block_{{ i }}" id="block_{{ i }}">
            <div class="conf-image absolutecenter">
                {% set image = block.bilde.first() %}
                <img src="{{ image.getUrl('plantegningKonfigurator') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
            </div>                            
        </div>
    {% endfor %}   
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: could you please add your HTML too? or partially working code snippet will be awesome.

Comment: This for sure could be simplified, but easier if you post relevant HTML markup. Here your logic is wrong because you set it outside of click handler

Comment: Please replace ``$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();`` with something like ``$(this).closest('parent-selector-here')``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this.

```
$('#chooseAnnexDropdown ul li').click(function(){
             var thisParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
             thisParent.find('.theProduct[data-num=' + $(this).attr('data-num') + ']').show().siblings().hide();

  });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at your HTML structure, but based on what it looks like you are doing, you can add your click handler to all the "li" elements and in that handler, just find the matching item to show and then hide it's siblings.

```
 $('#chooseAnnexDropdown ul li').click(function(){
      var dataNum = $(this).attr('data-num');
      //this could be done in a better way
      var thisParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
      thisParent.find('.theProduct[data-num=' + dataNum + ']').show().siblings().hide();

  });
```

Seeing your actual HTML would help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your JS code as follows:

Here we are hiding all the `div` on `document` ready and then on `click` of `li` we are grabbing its `data-num` and then finding the associated `div` to show it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".theProduct").hide(); //hide all div first

  $('#chooseAnnexDropdown ul li').click(function() {
    var thisAttr = $(this).attr('data-num');
    
    $(".theProduct").hide(); //hide all div first

    $("div[data-num='" + thisAttr + "']").show(); //show the matching div
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div id="chooseAnnexDropdown" class="confDropdown">
  <ul>
    <li class="block_2" data-num="block_2">Atelier</li>
    <li class="block_3" data-num="block_3">Bryggerhus</li>
    <li class="block_4" data-num="block_4">Smørebod</li>
    <li class="block_5" data-num="block_5">Bakstehus</li>
    <li class="block_6" data-num="block_6">Sportsrom</li>
    <li class="block_7" data-num="block_7">Boenhet</li>
    <li class="block_8" data-num="block_8">Ingen</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- end dropdown menu -->
<div class="theProduct" data-num="block_2" id="block_2">Atediver</div>
<div class="theProduct" data-num="block_3" id="block_3 ">Bryggerhus</div>
<div class="theProduct " data-num="block_4" id="block_4">Smørebod</div>
<div class="theProduct " data-num="block_5" id="block_5">Bakstehus</div>
<div class="theProduct " data-num="block_6" id="block_6">Sportsrom</div>
<div class="theProduct " data-num="block_7" id="block_7">Boenhet</div>
<div class="theProduct " data-num="block_8" id="block_8">Ingen</div>
```